# Power BI Desktop - Developer visual can't be loaded because it's not enabled

Tags: powerbi

I've successfully imported the .pbiviz file for my custom visual into Power BI Desktop, but the custom visual placeholder on the report says "Visual couldn't be loaded. The developer visual can't be loaded because it's not enabled in settings.". I can't find any settings in Power BI Desktop where I can enable this. Can someone please help?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not find the Setting in Power BI Desktop. You will find it in powerbi.com.

Login to powerbi.com and select `Settings`:

[image: Snap1]

Select `Developer` then check the `Enable Developer Visual for testing` checkbox.

[image: Snap2]

You can refer this link here: [PBI Custom visual](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/step-by-step-lab/creating-a-custom-visual/)

Comment: But it's enabled in PowerBI.com..that's how I tested the visual and exported it as a .pbiviz file.

Comment: Try `pbiviz update` and then export it again. Make sure your power bi desktop version is also updated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to install certificate:

https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-visuals/docs/step-by-step-lab/setting-up-the-developer-environment/#creating-and-installing-a-certificate